# My variable can't be seeing in testing

Tags: solidity, testing

Why when I'm trying to use acdmToken instance in "it" block, programm can't see it (undefined)?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'balanceOf' of undefined
```

Since I declared it on beforeEach.

```
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { ACDMToken, ACDMToken__factory, POPToken, POPToken__factory, TSTToken, TSTToken__factory, UniswapAdapter, UniswapAdapter__factory } from "../typechain";


describe("UniswapAdapter", function () {
    let bob: SignerWithAddress,
        alice: SignerWithAddress;
    let acdmToken: ACDMToken;
    let popToken: POPToken;
    let tstToken: TSTToken
    let uniswapAdapter: UniswapAdapter;


    before(async () => {
        [bob, alice] = await ethers.getSigners();
    })

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const ACDMToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("ACDMToken") as ACDMToken__factory;
        const POPToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("POPToken") as POPToken__factory;
        const TSTToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("TSTToken") as TSTToken__factory;
        const UniswapAdapter = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapAdapter") as UniswapAdapter__factory;
        const acdmToken = await ACDMToken.deploy();
        await acdmToken.deployed();
        const popToken = await POPToken.deploy();
        await popToken.deployed();
        const tstToken = await TSTToken.deploy();
        await tstToken.deployed();
        const uniswapAdapter = await UniswapAdapter.deploy(acdmToken.address, popToken.address, tstToken.address);
        await uniswapAdapter.deployed();
        console.log(await acdmToken.balanceOf(uniswapAdapter.address))
    })

    it("Checking  owner balance of tokens", async function () {
        const adcmBalance = ethers.utils.parseEther("100");
        console.log(await acdmToken.balanceOf(uniswapAdapter.address))
        //expect(await acdmToken.balanceOf(uniswapAdapter.address)).to.be.equal(adcmBalance)
    });
})


[![enter image description here][2]][2]



  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2Rg.png
```

Comment: in your `beforeEach()` `const acdmToken = await ACDMToken.deploy();` should be `acdmToken = await ACDMToken.deploy();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialised `acdmToken` near the top of your block scope so that you could access it in the child blocks, but when you assigned a value to `acdmToken` in your `beforeEach` you said `const acdmToken = ...`, which then limited the defined value to the scope of the `beforeEach(async () => {`

Instead, when you assign the value to `acdmToken`, rather just say `acdmToken = ...` instead of `const acdmToken = ...`